# Getting a backup files in a thread in efficent way

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, thread-safety

I need to create a backup files in thread in safe and efficient way .But the thread should get trigged when its complete it last task successfully else
ignore it.

**CreateBakeup function is called multiple times**

```
bool CreateBakeup()
{

//here i create a OrignalFile and pass to thread for a backup.
if (x_pthread_create (&pthreadId, NULL,
                                makeBackup,
                               (void*)  OrignalFile) != 0)
        {

              std::cout<<"failed to create a thread"<<std::endl;
                return FALSE;
        }

}
```

**I need this thread to be block untill  backup is completed sucessfully
 In between if any request comes from CreateBakeup ignore it. after sucessfully
 completed only this thread should be ready for other backup.**

```
static void * makeBackup(void *OrignalFile)
{

 if ((pthread_mutex_lock(&keyMutex)) != 0)
        {
                std::cout<<"failed pthread_mutex_lock() "<<std::endl;
        }

 std::ifstream Orignal((char *)OrignalFile);

  std::ofstream fin("/backupfile");
  fin<<Orignal.rdbuf();
  remove((char *)OrignalFile)



   if ((pthread_mutex_unlock(&keyMutex)) != 0)
        {
          std::cout<<" failed pthread_mutex_unlock() "<<std::endl;
        }

}
```

Comment: why no response at all .Is anything not good at all or question is not clearn or is bad?